# Wordpress: track down and remove pseudo element from wp_head

Tags: php, css, wordpress, header, styling

I have a site visible [here](http://www.tinywolf.uk/blog) where I have created a child theme in order to add a custom header and footer from the rest of the (non blog) website.

I've removed everthing from the existing header apart from `<?php wp_head(); ?>`
as this is required to call many other elements in the page. However at larger screen resolutions there is what appears to be a div present on the left hand side of the screen, which I would like to remove.

using firebug this element appears to be in the body, but i couldn't track it down any further. This must be a pseudo element of some kind?

Then i will be able to add in my header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your stylesheet, you have:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 59.6875em)
body:before {
...
}
```

This `body:before` pseudo-element is what is creating that "div" on the left hand side of the screen.

**Note**
The psuedo element properties begin on line 3893 of `style.css?ver=4.1.1`.